# Filter parameters in Power BI Embedded

Tags: azure, powerbi

We are developing a Power BI embedded app, where we have an Azure website containing a Power BI report, which is also uploaded on our Azure server.

I know I can set filter parameters in a Power BI app embedded in an iframe, like this:

```
function onFrameLoaded() {
var m = {
    action: "loadReport",
    reportId: reportId,
    accessToken: accessToken
};

iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(m), "*");
```

This works when you embed a Power BI report published on web. But it doesn't work on Power BI Embedded. Is there a way to accomplish the same kind of filtering in Power BI Embedded?

Comment: What are you passing in as the `accessToken`?  Are you passing in your embed JWT?

Comment: Also, are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: I am passing the token created by PowerBIToken.CreateReportEmbedToken(), and no I'm not seeing any errors in console.

Comment: Are you specifying the `oDataFilter` property in your message?

Comment: Yes, I didn't write it in the post but I am specifying oDataFilter property for object m.

Comment: Can you try adding a breakpoint in `function receiveMessage(event) {` on the iframe?  Verify that `isAppTokenEmbed = checkForAppToken(accessToken);` sets `isAppTokenEmbed` to `true`.  It should then call `loadReport(reportId, accessToken, oDataFilter);`.  Can you verify that?

Comment: I don't know what happened, but it started to work now. Maybe I was using an old version. Now, it works in Power Bi Embedded, just like it works in the regular version. Thanks for replying anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Power BI Embed URL-multiple filters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37943885/power-bi-embed-url-multiple-filters)

Answer (score 0):

Using the new(er) Power BI Embedded JS SDK, you can lose the iframe.postMessage method and let the SDK communicate to the embedded entity.

I can refer you to: http://aka.ms/pbijs to play around with the new version of the SDK.

Also, you can pass filters more advanced than OData (which you needed to put in the url), using: https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Filters
This can be done either during load (via the load config) or during interactions with the embedded report.