# How to pass parameter to PowerBI Embedded via embedded URL

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have an IFrame which shows a PowerBI embedded Report that having world map. Can I pass a parameter to PowerBI Embedded via embedded URl to filter my report based on a specific country.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Power BI Embed URL-multiple filters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37943885/power-bi-embed-url-multiple-filters)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you embed the report, add the following to the end of the iframe's URL:

`&$filter=tablename/fieldname+eq+'countryName'`

Comment: What if you need to not filter the page, but change the required parameter of the report to return the correct result set?