# Parameterised report in PowerBI

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'd like to make a report in PowerBI. This report will contain graphs and details for a particular product in my system. I'd like to paramaterise this report with the product code so that I first select a product and then the report is generated. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this:
[Query parameters in PowerBI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/deep-dive-into-query-parameters-and-power-bi-templates/)

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it's coming soon.

Comment: You can currently pass a single filter to parameterize the report.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986615/how-to-pass-parameter-to-powerbi-embedded-via-embedded-url for an example.