# PowerBI Embedded - Interactions between various widgets in a report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a PowerBI report. This report has multiple widgets in it. Is it possible to have interactivity between these widgets? Let's say I select a filter on one widget and it can be passed to another widgets within the same report to filter it?

Read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986615/how-to-pass-parameter-to-powerbi-embedded-via-embedded-url), and would like to verify if this concept can be extended to perform filtering across the widgets?