# Power BI Embedded odata filter

Tags: odata, powerbi-embedded

i am developing an asp.net mvc webapp that is integrating Power BI Embedded, which works just fine.

I want to filter the DataSet with an oDataFilter like that:

```
    load: function () {
        var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(this.element);
        var accessToken = this.getAccessToken();

        var initEventArgs = {
            message: {
                action: this.options.loadAction,
                accessToken: accessToken,
                oDataFilter: "Metrics/project eq 'auth'",
                width: computedStyle.width,
                height: computedStyle.height
            }
        };

        powerbi.utils.raiseCustomEvent(this.element, 'embed-init', initEventArgs);
        this.iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(initEventArgs.message), '*');
    }
```

This works like it should, i just get records which have the value "auth" in the row "project". However when i am extending the oDataFilter like that:

```
...
oDataFilter: "Metrics/project eq 'auth' or Metrics/project eq 'beta'",
...
```

I expect to get rows that have either the value "auth" or the value "beta" in the row "project". But it now completely disregards the filter passed to it and gives me all the records in that DataSet.

How do i achieve that particular filter scenario?

Greetings

Comment: The current odata filter only support a single filter expression which doesn't include and/or values.  The team is working on more robust filter support that will be released as part of enhancements to the JavaScript SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Ok that's a bummer. Is there any ETA for the rework?

Comment: Keep an eye on the [JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript) for updates on enhanced filtering support.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Power BI Embed URL-multiple filters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37943885/power-bi-embed-url-multiple-filters)