# How to add filters before loading reports

Tags: javascript, excel, iframe, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am new to power bi.

I have implemented multiple simple power bi reports where back-end is IMPORT not Direct Query and with Excel-sheet.

I have also embedded them successfully using power bi embedded and IFrame.
Now I have a challenges:

I want to filter my reports by date range.

before loading report using power bi embedded or IFrame, I want to apply two filters fromdate and todate.
these filters value will be chosen from web app datepicker, then on click of load, i want to show my report by applying these filters.

I have gone through following links, but still not understanding how to implement this:

[Power BI Embed URL-multiple filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37943885/power-bi-embed-url-multiple-filters)

https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Configuration-Details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even i got the same requirement where we have embedded report and from client side we have date range picker. Once you select date range then your report should filter.
I tried to do it pushing dates manually and it worked, which is from javascript.
Below is the sample code

```
    var fromDate = new Date("2011/10/30");
    fromDate = fromDate.toJSON();
    var toDate = new Date("2011/02/01");
    toDate = toDate.toJSON();

    $predefinedFilter1.on('click', function (event) {
        var models = window['powerbi-client'].models;
        const advancedFilter = new models.AdvancedFilter({
            table: "Time",
            column: "Date"
        }, "And", [
          {
              operator: "GreaterThan",
              value: fromDate
          },
          {
              operator: "LessThan",
              value: toDate
          }
        ]);
        //report.page("ReportSection3").setFilters([advancedFilter])
        report.setFilters([advancedFilter])
          .catch(errors => {
              // Handle error
          });
    });
```

Hope you can understand this.

Comment: thanks for above code. I will try this now. But In latest power bi desktop version, slicer control is updated for date...Now we can choose from date and to date with date picker control and/or date range also

Comment: Yeah i saw that, but my requirement is like to have it on client side on the UI shell, also it should apply filter in both labels page and report.

Comment: Are you embedding report in client side or having .Net MVC application ?

Comment: yes, I am embedding reports in .net MVC application

Comment: Ok i have a question here, can you provide me a sample code for applying filter in .NET MVC.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/power-bi-embedded-integrate-report-into-web-app/    - I have used this code to show reports in .net MVC app, there is filter control in javascript code. but my requirement is to call that javascript code from my own date picker not from report filter pane...I am hiding that filter pane as client does not want it...client wants it in separate date picker outside report control on view and their selected value should get applied on report.

Comment: tried above code with my javascript code and it works! thanks.