# [Power BI desktop]-Can create a report this template?

Tags: powerbi

I'm new power BI desktop. I want create a report like this template? I tried but I can't do that.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B59n3.png)
Please help me.

Comment: This question shows little effort. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Power BI Embed URL-multiple filters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37943885/power-bi-embed-url-multiple-filters)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different ways you can achieve this however this is how I would go about it.

The table itself can be created easily by inputting the table visual. Here the settings can be configured through the formatting tab.

The biggest issue you are having looks like it could be to do with the positive, negative numbers. There are actually a couple of really nice visuals that could help you with this: [https://app.powerbi.com/visuals](https://app.powerbi.com/visuals/)

The other alternative is to create your own visuals using R.